# ingress Failed build model due to couldn't auto-discover subnets: unable to discover at least one subnet

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

I am getting an error "ingress  Failed build model due to couldn't auto-discover subnets: unable to discover at least one subnet" while deploying ingress in EKS.

**Steps already taken:**

1. Cluster Name is correct in Deployment file
2. below annotation is am using in Ingress-Resource file

annotations:

```
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internal
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: ip
kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
kubernetes.io/role/internal-elb: 1
alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/subnets: subnet-xxxx, subnet-yyy, subnet-zzz
kubernetes.io/cluster/<ClusterName>: owned   ---> (I am using correct cluster name)
```

**Key point:**
I am using private subnet in EKS, Subnets were separately created with proper Tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
2. below annotation is am using in Ingress-Resource file
...
kubernetes.io/role/internal-elb: 1
...
kubernetes.io/cluster/<ClusterName>: owned ---> (I am using correct
 cluster name)
```

The above are tags and not for annotation usage. Try tag the 3 subnets in your question on the AWS console with `kubernetes.io/role/internal-elb: 1` and `kubernetes.io/cluster/<ClusterName>: owned`; so that the LB controller can discover them.

Comment: Well thanks, the issue was fixed as the IAM role json was using oldest version.